# Reporting software subscriptions

Tags: united-states, income-tax, small-business, software

I have some software subscriptions for my indie developer business (Sole Proprietorship -- file as an individual).  Xamarin and MSDN.  I generally pay for a year at a time.  The amounts involved are not small -- hundreds of dollars up to a few thousand.  Two parts to my question:

1)  How should I report the subscriptions on my US income taxes?
2)  How do I get TurboTax to do the correct thing, given the answer to part 1?

Comment: Do you file as an individual or as a corporation?

Answer (score 1):

Generally prepaid services should be capitalized over the period prepaid. But if it is [up to a year](http://petershannonco.com/resources/taxtopics/expenses-one-year-rule/) - you can just expense them.

As to the technicalities - you can contact Intuit support, but you should be able to put it in the same area where you put all your other business expenses. If you're a sole proprietor - that would be Schedule C.